# How Can I Get Started with PhoneGap in Eclipse?

Tags: cordova

Trying to create my first PhoneGap project in eclipse. I have followed the Getting Started tutorial but that only seems to help in a best case scenario. My guess is that if they make the tutorials vague enough people will pay them for adequate help.

Following this tutorial: [Getting Started with Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)

When I run the create command I get the following error (see below). My guess that my environment is not ready. I have installed the Android SDK, I have the Java SDK installed and in my path. The only part that I am not clear on is the Apache Ant. I thought that was installed along with Eclipse?

```
Missing one of the following:
JDK: http://java.oracle.com
Android SDK: http://developer.android.com
Apache ant: http://ant.apache.org
```

What do I need to do to fix this problem and successfully create a PhoneGap project in Eclipse?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. If one follows the exact tutorial from Apache Cordova documentation, she will get to the error mentioned above. I did exactly the same thing, and got the same error, even after I installed Apache Ant and setting the path as mentioned below. However, after little more digging, and checking install instructions for Ant, I did the following two other things: set ANT_HOME path to root folder where I installed Ant and JAVA_HOME to root folder or Java JDK (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01 in my case). After that, it worked.

Comment: Yeah I think they will just let any ole body moderate around here. Judging from the responses I am not alone when having this issue..

Comment: Unfortunately any ol' body would necessarily include those with an interest in charging for PhoneGap advice.

Comment: I have same problem, i solve it, if you can't find where is problem, go and edit create.bat file and echo %%~$PATH:X in for loop to see witch file is lost; you can find it easly;) i notice my ant.bat file can't be founded, so i move directory path to the begging of line and it works magically;  PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;C:\ant\bin;C:\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on Windows because I just finished resolving the same error.

What I did:

- Install the latest JDK [1]
- Install Apache Ant binary [2]
- Install Android SDK [3]

After all of those were installed I appended the below paths to my Path system variable which can be found at:

**Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced tab > Environment Variables button > System variables**

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;C:\Users\Rob\Documents\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools

Be aware that my username is in those paths so yours will be different. Don't forget the semi-colon between the existing path and what you will be adding.

Depending on your usage of the above tools, it may be cleaner to add the path to the create.bat script.

1. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
2. http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi
3. http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I added the Ant and Java variables and paths in my windows environment but still unable to get it to work. I ended up using an eclipse plugin from AppLaud that creates PhoneGap / Android projects from a template with options to help bootstrap you project.

Comment: This proposed solution failed to work for me as well.

Comment: This worked for me. Originally didn't work because my Android SDK folder didn't have the platform-tools folder. I'm assuming this gets created when you install the Android SDK into Eclipse.

Like JBeckton, I first attempted Applaud, but this was of no use to me because it does not support v2.2 of PhoneGap. You can point Applaud to a newer version of PhoneGap, but when I tried it failed to find the necessary files. So in other words, not much use!